# Возможно ли как-то работать с курсором внутри другого курсора?

Tags: sqlite, cursor

Моя БД состоит из двух таблиц. В процесе постройки List'a мне нужно взять имя из первой и n-ое количество номером связаных с этим именем из второй.

```
Cursor cMyNewPeople = db.query("myNewPeople", null, null, null, null, null, null);



if (cMyNewPeople !=null && cMyNewPeople.getCount()>0) {
        cMyNewPeople.moveToFirst();
        do {

            Cursor nc = db.rawQuery("select type, number from myCell where name = ?",
                    new String[] {""+cMyNewPeople.getInt(0)});
            nc.moveToFirst();
            do {
                numbers = nc.getString(0) + ": " + nc.getString(1) + "\n";
            } while (nc.moveToNext());
            Log.d("RingApp", "numbers = " + numbers);
            list.add(new ContactItem(cMyNewPeople.getInt(0), cMyNewPeople.getString(1), "", numbers));
            numbers = "";
        } while (cMyNewPeople.moveToNext());
    }
```

Структура таблиц:

```
 db.execSQL("create table myNewPeople " +
            "(id integer primary key autoincrement, " +
            "name text);");
    db.execSQL("create table myCell " +
        "(id integer primary key autoincrement, id_people integer, number text, type text);");
```

Желаемый результат:
Записать в строку тип_номера и номер для каждого человека. Человеку может быть присвоено несколько номеров.

Comment: Во-первых, не очень понятно, что за язык используется (Java? C#?) и что вообще происходит. Во-вторых, возможно, вам просто нужен JOIN-запрос.

Comment: Покажите структуру таблиц и структуру желаемого результата.

Comment: Дополнил код, структуру таблиц